# ID value in Facebook Comments.Create callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, comments, facebook-javascript-sdk

According to [the Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), the `comment.create` callback contains a Comment ID property:

```
{
  href: "",         /* Open Graph URL of the Comment Plugin */
  commentID: "",    /* The commentID of the new comment */
}
```

However I'm seeing that the callback contains a common ID property that doesn't change across the comments.  For example, when i debug the callback I get an `commentID` value of `"10150259852273822"`, but the value doesn't change for any comment left on that page.  Below is a sample for the comments from the Graph API, notice the ID is the same across multiple comments, but its appended by a `"_XXXX"` number that appears to actually be the identifier.

```
 {
    "id": "10150259852273822_17973898",
    "from": {
       "name": "XXXXXX",
       "id": "XXXXX"
    },
    "message": "newest comment",
    "created_time": "2011-08-24T19:24:02+0000"
 },
 {
    "id": "**10150259852273822**_17973932",
    "from": {
       "name": "XXXXX",
       "id": "XXXXX"
    },
    "message": "brand newest comment.",
    "created_time": "2011-08-24T19:25:40+0000"
 }
```

Does anyone know how you can actually get the full identifier via the comment.create event?  Or is there another field that can be used to predict the `commonid_commentID` format?

Answer (score 5):

The comment ID from the callback is in fact the "post_fbid".
Here is how you can get the comment (and the data associated with it) :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
    var commentQuery = FB.Data.query("SELECT text, fromid FROM comment WHERE post_fbid='"+response.commentID+"' AND object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url='"+response.href+"')");
    var userQuery = FB.Data.query("SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid in (select fromid from {0})", commentQuery);

    FB.Data.waitOn([commentQuery, userQuery], function() {
        // Do whatever you want with the data
        console.log(commentQuery.value[0].text);
        console.log(userQuery.value[0].name)
        console.log(userQuery.value[0].uid);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you need/want the ID for. Perhaps we can come up with a better solution for what you need.

The common ID element is most likely (off the top of my head) specific to that comment form. And the additional bit is the "true" id of the comment as it were.

The full identifier of the comment is the whole element, your number that doesn't change and the appended element post the underscore.

Take a look here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/
And at the example graph URL.

The full string included underscored element is fully part of the comment ID

Comment: What I'm trying to do to get the full identifier (e.g. pageid_commentid) during the callback function.  Otherwise I don't know how to access the comment via the graph api.   I can only access ALL comments with the page URL not just the new one.

Comment: Well since the response returns the comment is as pageid_commentid why not just javascript split on it? If you are after a specific comment you might have to loop thru them all or you might be able to do it with some FQL.